# If I have a hypothesis as to a solution, should it be a comment or an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

What should I do in these instances? It usually happens with "why" questions more than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

It should be a comment for preference.  If it doesn't have a firm answer or suggestion then it's effectively discussion.  It may well allow another user to bounce off it and create a genuine answer, but the best place is in a comment.  If it's a good one, it can still be up voted as a great comment.

The only problem with using a comment is the lack of newline ability, and the fact that there is a character limit.  I have on occasion posted what I new to be too long for a comment even though that's what it was as a question, but I put a proviso explaining that at the top asking people not to vote on it.  Technically, that's not really a good thing to do, but the guy needed some help reading between the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!